# cmake try_compile: Using library found in configure

Tags: cmake

I am building a project with cmake. The project uses the external library plplot; I have configured cmake to the library and headers, and that is cached in variables `${PLPLOT_LIBRARY}, ${PLPLOT_LIB_PATH} and ${PLPLOT_INCLUDE_PATH}`. In the plplot library a function has changed name: `plwid -> plwidth` and I want to detect that. I have written a small `try_compile()` test:

```
try_compile(HAVE_PLWID ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} cmake/tests/test_plwid.c)
```

However this test will always fail, because I have to pass header and library information to the `try_compile` process. Invoking `gcc` manually like this:

```
gcc -I${PLPLOT_INCLUDE_PATH} cmake/tests/test_plwid.c -L${PLPLOT_LIB_PATH} -l${PLPLOT_LIBRARY}
```

works. However I don understand how to pass the necessary flags to the `try_compile`command: I have tried:

```
 try_compile(HAVE_PLWID ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} cmake/tests/test_plwid.c
             INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${PLPLOT_INCLUDE_PATH}
             LINK_DIRECTORIES ${PLPLOT_LIB_PATH}
             LINK_LIBRARIES ${PLPLOT_LIBRARY})
```

Then I just get the cmake configure error:

```
Attempt at a recursive or nested TRY_COMPILE in directory

    /path/to/build
```

I am quite confident the `${PLPLOT_XXX}` variables are correct, at least the rest of the build works fine based on these variables.

**Update:** If I invoke `cmake`with the `--debug_trycompile` command and go to the `build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp` directory and invoke `cmake`there manually as:

```
cmake . -DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=/path/plplot/include -DLINK_DIRECTORIES=/path/to/plplot/lib -DLINK_LIBRARIES=plplotd
```

The test program will build and link correctly; so it seems the challenge is to pass these options correctly to the `try_compile()` `cmake` command invocation?

Answer (score 7):

The `LINK_DIRECTORIES` and `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` cannot be passed as options to [`try_compile`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html) but have to passed as extra flags with the `CMAKE_FLAGS` option in the following way:

```
try_compile(HAVE_PLWID "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/temp" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/test_plwid.c"
             LINK_LIBRARIES ${PLPLOT_LIBRARY}
             CMAKE_FLAGS 
                  "-DINCLUDE_DIRECTORIES=${PLPLOT_INCLUDE_PATH}"
                  "-DLINK_DIRECTORIES=${PLPLOT_LIB_PATH}")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering - unfortunately this gives the cmake configure error: "Attempt at recursive or nested TRY_COMPILE in directory /path/to/build". The actual try_compile() command is in a subdirectory - if that matters?

Comment: Try using a different binary dir for the `try_comile`. See updated answer.

Comment: Hmmm - still no cigar. No I get the cmake configure error: "CMake Error: "The source directory /path/to/cmake/tests/test_plwid.c" is a file not a directory.

Comment: Try using a path relative to `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` for the file to be compiled and add quotes to the binary directory.